# I get this error "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" when I use highchart

Tags: jquery-plugins, highcharts

I am using timeseries chart from highchart plugin as follow:

```
var series1={
                            type: 'area',
                            color:lineColors[numOfLines],
                            name: legends[numOfLines],
                            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                            pointStart:Date.UTC(dateStart[0], dateStart[1], dateStart[2]) ,
                            data: democrat};
                    var series2={
                            type: 'area',
                            color:lineColors[numOfLines+1],
                            name: legends[numOfLines+1],
                            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                            pointStart:Date.UTC(dateStart[0], dateStart[1], dateStart[2]) ,
                            data: repub};
                    youDynamicSeries.push(series1);
                    youDynamicSeries.push(series2);}
```

and after creating the series I create the chart like this:

```
highcharttimeseries(youDynamicSeries,xLabel,'trend_chart');
```

and highcharttimeseries function is as follow:

```
function highcharttimeseries(series,date,chartcontainer)
```

{

```
 $('#'+chartcontainer).highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minRange: 7 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'middle',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
 fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1:0, y1: 5, x2: 0, y2: 0},
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba(f,f,f,f)')]
                        ]                   
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 3
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series:series

      });
    }
```

Now when I run it I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help what is wrong with my code?(I appreciate any help in advance)

Comment: Could you repliacte your example as live demo (on jsFiddle.net) ?

Comment: thanks @SebastianBochan for answering I just found the problem I had to convert the array that I am passing to series to float.

Comment: Makes sense, so at this moment works well?

Comment: Yes also there was another mistake, in my code in a if else statement I  was  mistakenly passing a series that was not exist so with fixing all those now it works.By the way 5thanks for following up this post and thanks for spending effort to solve this problem